# Using Grunt, Newer and Watch to optimize a bunch of images

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I started today getting used to grunt. I wanted to create a grunt package? script? module? task? which optimizes all images that will be uploaded to a certain folder (uploads/ ... it's a wordpress installation).

After some fiddling, I've create this small Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        imagemin: { 
            dynamic: { 
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../uploads', 
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: '../uploads'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            options: { nospawn: true},
            scripts: {
                files: ['../uploads/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                tasks: ['newer:imagemin']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['newer:imagemin','watch']);
}
```

It seems to work fine, the task first tries to optimize all existing images (if they are not already optimized), after this watch ensures that the optimize task runs whenever a picture in the uploads folder changes, newer ensures that only new files will be optimized.

Because I'm just started with grunt, is there anything I missed? What would happen if the upload takes a long time, will watch already start the task on a unfinished file and how could I prevent it?